# How to create a Jupyter cell using ipywidgets button?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to use a button widget to create a cell of code below the button or at the bottem of the ipynb.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython

def create_new_cell(contents):
    shell = get_ipython()
    payload = dict(
        source='set_next_input',
        text=contents,
        replace=False,
    )
    shell.payload_manager.write_payload(payload, single=False)
    
a_button = widgets.Button(
    description='Button A',
)
def func_a(b):
    create_new_cell("print('abcd')")
a_button.on_click(func_a)
display(a_button)
```

I expect the new cell of code would be created after I click the button but not, until I run this code again. Only this way the new cell can be created.

Is there a way to realize that? Thanks!